# MySQL grouping results by specific field

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'test' like so:

```
id     | location_id | date
1      | 1           | 2017-01-02
2      | 1           | 2017-01-03
3      | 2           | 2017-01-04
4      | 1           | 2017-01-05
```

I would like a SELECT statement that selects one row per location_id and ordered by date.

My specific problem is creating a statement that'll work with MySQL 5.7.1 and later, due to the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY requirements (and similar strict standards with other DBs)

```
SELECT id, location_id , date FROM test GROUP BY location_id  ORDER BY date
```

Works, but it's invalid the day the MySQL db is upgraded.

```
SELECT id, location_id , date FROM test GROUP BY location_id, id, date  ORDER BY date
```

Is valid, but does not work, it returns all the results.

What I would like is to obtain the results of the first SELECT query above, but with valid SQL that's future-proof, which returns:

```
id     | location_id | date
1      | 1           | 2017-01-02
3      | 2           | 2017-01-04
```

Any help or insight on how to get around this appreciated!

Comment: What value do you want returned after grouping? We need to know this to know how to deal with multiple records being grouped together. e.g. Max ID?

`SELECT Max(ID), location_id, date FROM test GROUP BY location_id, date ORDER BY date` would give you 1 record per location/date combination and when two or more records are found we display the maximum id found between them

Comment: Hi Matt, I've edited my comment, I want the results of my first query but with future-proof SQL as I think it'll fail in future versions of MySQL when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample data you've provided you want to do this:

```
SELECT  MIN(id) AS ID,
        Location_ID,
        MIN(Date) AS Date
FROM    test
GROUP BY Location_ID
ORDER BY Date
```

We've applied aggregate functions to id and date so you only need to keep location_id in the group by. and on the same data you seem to only choose the smallest id - date. This is probably a mislead assumption so let me know

EDIT

Based on our chat, I've come up with the following:

```
SELECT id, location_id, Date
FROM (
  SELECT t1.*,
         @cur := IF(location_id = @id, @cur+1, 1) AS RowNumber,
         @id := location_id AS IdCache
  FROM docs t1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @id:=(SELECT MIN(location_id) FROM docs), @cur:=0) AS init
   ORDER BY t1.location_id, date
) PartitionedData
WHERE RowNumber = 1
order by location_id
```

What I've done is replicate the methodology of `MSSQL's ROW_NUMBER()` and partitioned on `location_id`. To get a better understanding of that function read up on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)

Given the following example data:

```
1 | 1 | 2017-01-02
2 | 1 | 2017-01-03
3 | 2 | 2017-01-04
4 | 1 | 2017-01-05
```

The view, `PartitionedData`, will return the following data set:

```
id | location_id | date       | RowNumber | IdCache
1  | 1           | 2017-01-02 | 1         | 1
2  | 1           | 2017-01-03 | 2         | 1
4  | 1           | 2017-01-05 | 3         | 1
3  | 2           | 2017-01-04 | 1         | 2
```

The "Partitioning" is based on what we are choosing as the @id and then our order by. If we change the order by to be `t1.location_id, date desc` then our dataset would be:

```
id | location_id | date       | RowNumber | IdCache
4  | 1           | 2017-01-05 | 1         | 1
2  | 1           | 2017-01-03 | 2         | 1
1  | 1           | 2017-01-02 | 3         | 1
3  | 2           | 2017-01-04 | 1         | 2
```

So depending on how we order the date we can select the latest or first date - you'll have to handle the asc/desc in the php.

Finally, our returned data will coincide with the id so the above query will output:

```
id | location_id | date
1  | 1           | 2017-01-02
3  | 2           | 2017-01-04
```

Let me know if this is closer to what you are looking for!

Comment: Hi Matt, that's closer than I've gotten thusfar, thanks! However, as you mentioned the assumption of the id needing to be the minimum is wrong, as the date could be anything, and this is just a theoretical example for a much bigger set of data with more columns I may want to filter (but not include in the select).

The ID is unique though... so some sort of aggregator that doesn't affect the results could work.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I think to move forward I need to understand.. What is it you are actually trying to show with this data? Then maybe we can find something that'll work :)

Comment: I want to show a list next upcoming test items at each location, i.e. show the next test at each location in the table.

Comment: Hey, I've made a chat room called Marcus. Come join it - will be easier to discuss this :) [think this will work](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151620/marcus)

Comment: @marcus Hey Marcus, I've updated my post. Let me know

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks, for the intents of this question, your response answers it!

If you're interested in maybe doing some paid work on this kind of thing, let's get in touch... maybe you could create a private chat room for us to exchange contact info?

Comment: Hi @marcus, not sure how to create a private room on the phone however feel free to add me on Skype, matt.barber94. Interested to hear what youve got to offer. Glad the answer was what you were looking for.

Comment: added. Thanks again for the solution, it's working very well so far!

Answer (score 0):

Does SELECT DISTINCT give you what you need?

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, location_id , date FROM test GROUP BY location_id, id, date  ORDER BY date
```

Comment: No, because DISTINCT provides unique values of id, location_id and date combined, meaning all the values in the table above are already unique.

Your statement returns all 4 results. See my OP again, I've added what results I want to see.